# org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException - 'org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl

Tags: android, android-build, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am getting the following error while running the build in our internal CI Server.

> org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id:
>   'org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl', version: '0.18.1'] was not found in
>   any of the following sources:
>
> - Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
> - Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl:org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl.gradle.plugin:0.18.1')
>     Searched in the following repositories:
>     Gradle Central Plugin Repository

app/buildSrc/build.gradle.kts
Below is the code in build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}
```

Even though I tried to include the repositories above or below the plugins didnt make any difference.

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}
repositories {
      maven("https://ci.mycompany.com/jcenter")
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had to add pluginManagement to the settings.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
       repositories {
                  maven("https://ci.mycompany.com/jcenter")
               }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean settings.gradle of the project or is it another one inside buildSrc?